How to name algorithm in c++ for process items in collection which can add or remove items?
I search for some std:: algorithm but failed. I want to process items from input iterator til last iterator and write output into out iterator. Note output can be less or more then input stream. So I write example to show what exactly I need:
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

void some_algorithm_name(auto it_beg, auto it_end, auto it_out, auto func)
{
    for (; it_beg != it_end; it_beg++)
    {
        func(*it_beg, it_out);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace std;
    string_view in = "abcdefaa";
    string      out;
    some_algorithm_name(begin(in),
                        end(in),
                        back_inserter(out),
                        [](char ch, auto& out_it)
                        {
                            switch (ch)
                            {
                                case 'a': // duplicate
                                {
                                    *out_it++ = 'a';
                                    *out_it++ = 'a';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'b': // skip
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'c': // change/transform
                                {
                                    *out_it++ = 'd';
                                    break;
                                }
                                case 'd': // change/transform
                                {
                                    *out_it++ = 'c';
                                    break;
                                }
                                default: // copy
                                {
                                    *out_it++ = ch;
                                }
                            }
                        });

    string expected = "aadcefaaaa";
    cout << "input: " << quoted(in) << endl;
    cout << "output: " << quoted(expected) << (expected == out ? "==" : "!=")
         << quoted(out) << endl;
    return 0;
}

Is any library or framework where I can find such algorithm? Or maybe you can offer some name for it?

Your some_algorithm_name just plumbs out_it to the callback. If you let the lambda capture out_it instead this is just std::for_each.

What, something like std::transform perhaps?

std::for_each - is plan B - but it can't separate algorithm from lambda so people will use it like [&] - capture all every type

it_out really looks like old user data of old C-callback, except it doesn't use type erasure...

BTW which C++ standard you can use?

@MarekR I use c++23, but c++17 should work the same

BTW you have stated question title is strange way: "How to name algorithm ...". In this form I understand you have some strange algorithm which you like give nice name so API is useful. Meanwhile you were actually asking: which std algorithm use to improve some code.

"So I write example to show what exactly I need:" -- An example of input and expected output, along with an explanation why the output is expected, would do a better job of showing "exactly" what you need. Interpreting content from code is rarely "exact" (but having the code is still good, so don't drop it).

@MarekR yes, I want to find out name for this simple algorithm or find out existing analog. std::accumulate - is what is it, but I still want better name, cause I'm not accumulating I just process items... Your solution with ranges + coroutines - nice!

One of approaches is to use standard algorithm std::accumulate declared in header <numeric>. For example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::string_view in = "abcdefaa";
    std::string out;

    auto lambda = []( auto result, auto ch )
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'a': // duplicate
            result.append( 2, 'a' );
            break;
        case 'b': // skip
            break;
        case 'c': // change/transform
            result += 'd';
            break;
        case 'd': // change/transform
            result += 'c';
            break;
        default: // copy
            result += ch;
            break;
        }

        return  result;
    };

    out = std::accumulate( std::begin( in ), std::end( in ), std::string(), lambda );

    std::cout << "in = " << in << '\n';
    std::cout << "out = " << out << '\n';
}

The program output is
in = abcdefaa
out = aadcefaaaa

I quickly showed one of approaches based on standard algorithms.
However it seems there is better to use the old range-based for loop.

in this case you have to add overloaded operator + for template T for algorithm accumulate, it slow for strings. So it is plan C

Several copies of strings though pre C++20 :-/

@leanid.chaika: Accumulator is provided, no operator+ needed.

@leanid.chaika I quickly showed one of approaches based on standard algorithms.

With C++23 with use of coroutines and ranges, this code can be nicely formed:
std::generator<char> decodeCharacter(char ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a': // duplicate
    {
        co_yield 'a';
        co_yield 'a';
        break;
    }
    case 'b': {
        break;
    }
    case 'c': // change/transform
    {
        co_yield 'd';
        break;
    }
    case 'd': // change/transform
    {
        co_yield 'c';
        break;
    }
    default: // copy
    {
        co_yield ch;
    }
    }
}

std::string decode(std::string_view in)
{
    using namespace std::views;
    return std::ranges::to<std::string>(in | transform(decodeCharacter) | join);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/b3fn1sTre
or alternative version https://godbolt.org/z/fPd6aa3vK

this solution is coollest but I can't checkit out on my msvc compiler not "generator" header, but I like it, and what about speed for things like coroutine generators?
